# Asp.net MVC Composite class custom model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, composite

I've searched all over the web but not finding the solution for the following problem:

Say I have three ViewModel classes

```
public class ViewModelNewPerson
{
    public string PersonName;
    public string Address;
    public string EyeColor;
    //etc
}

public class ViewModelSelectPerson
{
    public int SelectedPersonId;
}

public class ViewModelComposite
{
    public ViewModelSelectPerson selectViewModel;
    public ViewModelNewPerson newPersonViewModel;
}
```

and I want to do the following things:

In the `Controller` I want to create a `GET` `Action` which uses the class `ViewModelComposite` as its Get model, and in the view I want the user choose from the following two available actions: to choose a existed person, and to add a new person as the selected value.

So I need to create two forms in the `View`, and there would be two `POST` `Action`s added to the `Controller` using the Post model of class `ViewModelNewPerson` and `ViewModelSelectPerson`.

My question is, how can I do the manual model binding using a Custom Model Binder that can convert the Composite class of `ViewModelComposite` to `ViewModelNewPerson` in the `Action` of create a new person, and to `ViewModelSelectPerson` in the `Action` of select an existing person?

EDIT:

Now I have an idea of decomposing the class `ViewModelComposite` and declare every property in the two classes into the composite class, and the default model binder will do the trick, I think. But that'll drop the composite pattern, and is not something I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use one single view model in your form,  you would have a post action that receives your single view model.

In your Controller code:

```
public ActionResult GetSomeData(MyCustomViewModel  model){
      // add the first element
      var person = Person.Add(model.Person);
      // update the second object in model, with related / needed ID
      model.PersonContent.PersonId = person.id;
      // add in related content
      var AddedContent = PersonContent.Add(model.PersonContent);
}
```

single form, multiple actions, multiple tables

Comment: Ok, I found my composite not making sense, so I decomposite that. Thanks for your answer.